# How to compare two pg_fetch_array results in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I would like to compare values from two different database which are in two difference servers. So, I have queries in two different database and converted that to array using `pg_fetch_array()` function. I used `array_diff()` function but it is not giving expected result. The values in the each array will be like the following:

```
Array1=[[no=>100,quantity=>200,item=3353],no=>101,quantity=>20,item=3354]]
Array2=[[no=>100,quantity=>120,item=3353],no=>101,quantity=>20,item=3354],no=>1012,quantity=>20,item=3354]]

I should get response as: Array3=[[no=>100,quantity=>80,item=3353],no=>1012,quantity=>20,item=3354]]



<?php
    $row1 = pg_fetch_assoc($query1);
     $row2 = pg_fetch_assoc($query2);
    print_r($result);

    ?>
```

Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff()` is going to return the difference in the array, as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). You are going to have do something where you iterate the arrays, compare, and then return the value you want.